# Add increasing time to a date (php)

Tags: php, mysql

Hello everybody and thanks for taking the time to read this ;

I was wandering if I have a variable that contains a formatted date like this :

```
07/02/2012
```

That I obtained with the following query

```
date_format(data,'%d/%m/%Y') as data_scadenza,
```

How can I loop this date to have something like this:

```
2012-02-07 11:53:00, 2012-02-07 11:54:00, 2012-02-07 11:55:00, etc.
```

Thanks everybody in advance, was wandering how to do this either in PHP or directly in the MySQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through it in PHP.

```
$num = 5; //5 values will be printed
$phpdate = strtotime('07/02/2012'); //converts to timestamp
$phpdate += 11*3600 + 53*60; //to set initial offset to 11:53:00
for($i=0;$i<$num;$i++)
echo date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s', $phpdate + 60*$i).",";
```

Output:

```
2012-07-02 11:53:00,2012-07-02 11:54:00,2012-07-02 11:55:00,2012-07-02 11:56:00,2012-07-02 11:57:00,
```

Comment: Beautiful execttelly what i was looking for Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 0):

Have a number table with values from 1 to 100 and use this

```
select date_format(data+interval number minute,'%d/%m/%Y') as data_scadenza your_table as t1
cross join number_table as num
```

Comment: iam sure this would work but creating another table unfortunately can not do for technical reasons , can you not achieve the same with a loop in php ?